# External ThinkpadKeyboard's Thinkvantage and Mic-Mute-Keys in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, thinkpad, ubuntu-9.10, hal

xev does not react to the pressing of the two button mentioned above.
Thus xorg doesn't recognize them.

How can I "enable" them?

http://lenovoblogs.com/designmatters/?p=2364 - that's the keyboard

Comment: I love the keyboards thinkpads have. +1 for excellent taste. Maybe they use the same modules thinkpads use for their special keys? thinkwiki might be a good place to root around for answers.

Comment: thanks! thinkwiki sadly doesn't even have anything on it. I wrote a blogpost a while ago because even the trackpoint does not work according to existing tutorials. http://www.nrtm.de/index.php/2010/01/13/howto-configure-the-trackpoint-of-the-thinkpad-keyboard/

Answer (score 1):

Well I did not find a real solution, but in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS: The Lucid Lynx it works out of the box.